# Spring Constructor Problems

Tags: java, spring

I am having trouble setting up a constructor for a @service.  "url" and "template" are used in many places in my code and wanted to initialize it in just one place. Here is the code,

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQServices {

    @Autowired
    public RabbitMQServices() {

        // Create RabbitMQ management url
        this.url = "http://" + rmqfqdn + ":" + rmqmgmtport;

        // Create http template
line 36 ==> this.template.getInterceptors()
            .add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(rmqadminname,
               rmqadminpw));

    }

    // Create vhost
    private String createVhost(RabbitmqRepository repo) {

        // Create default parameters
        result = "OK";

        // Create service uri
        String uri = url + "/api/vhosts/" + repo.getTenantid() + "-vh";

        // Create header entity
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.set("content-type", "application/json");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(header);

        try {

        // Go create vhost
        template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);

        } catch(Exception e) {

            result = "FAIL: " + e;
        }

        return result;
    }

// Class variables
String result;
String tenantpw;
String url;
RestTemplate template;

// RabbitMQ Server URI
@Value("${rabbitmq.server.fqdn}")
private String rmqfqdn;

// RabbitMQ Server Managment port
@Value("${rabbitmq.server.management.port}")
private String rmqmgmtport;

// RabbitMQ Server administrator name
@Value("${rabbitmq.server.adminname}")
private String rmqadminname;

// RabbitMQ Server administrator password
@Value("${rabbitmq.server.adminpw}")
private String rmqadminpw;
```

I am getting the following error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.belcan.services.RabbitMQServices.<init>(RabbitMQServices.java:36) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Line 36 is the this.template line in the constructor,

```
this.template.getInterceptors() ...
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring. It's just a good old NPE. You can't call a method on a variable that you have not initialized.

Comment: Unless it's a static method!

Comment: Tried static but still NPE error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked,

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQServices implements InitializingBean {

     RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

     @Override
     public void afterPropertiesSet() {

         // Create RabbitMQ management url
         this.url = "http://" + rabbitmqfqdn + ":" + rbtmqmgmtport;

         // Create http template
         template.getInterceptors()
             .add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(rbtmqadminname,
                rbtmqadminpw));

}
```

I tried @Autowired RestTemplate template with the InitializingBean class and it did not work.  I tried RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate() and it worked. RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate() was a guess and I am not sure why this worked.  I assumed RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate() was an executable.  Any idea's why this worked.  By the way, thanks for the comments.  They got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an NPE because `template` is null. You need to autowire `RestTemplate`

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate template;
```

Comment: I tried @Autowired RestTemple but still get the NPE error.

Comment: @skmansfield because Spring can't inject the fields of an object before the object is constructed. And the constructor is what constructs the object. So the autowired fields are null in the constructor. Use constructor injection (preferred), and/or use `@PostConstruct` (read the documentation to know how). But anyway, the constructor of a component shouldn't configure an autowired RestTemplate. This should be done when creating the RestTemplate. Or the component should have its own RestTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a constructor, you better use the @PostConstruct annotation. Which is not a Spring annotation but it is located in the J2EE library.

By default Spring is not aware of this annotation. You have to register it in your configuration. Add

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

To your configuration.xml

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
   // init your Spring bean here..
}
```

The init method is called just after the bean is constructed. At that point you are shure that everything in your bean is autowired. Don't forget to autowire your RestTemplate on which you are getting the NullPointerException on.